# pde, fourier series

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I want to know of some sources where I can learn the methods to solve equations like this:

$-d^2f/dx^2 = e^x$ on [0,2pi], $f \in V$ = {periodic, $C^{\infty} \cap L^2$}, $f(0) = 1$

The prof. talked specifically about using eigenvalues and fourier series.

Comment: You may want to check your notation again.

Comment: I forgot the 'f' in the beginning... other than that this is verbatim what he wrote... I think I am supposed to use Fourier transform.

Comment: I'm not sure how the equation above produces anything periodic.  To solve the above, you simply integrate twice to get $f(x) = a + b x - e^x$.  You have one boundary condition, which still leaves you with a free parameter.

Answer (score 1):

The approach your Pofessor was talking is called Galerkin approximations and more specifically Spectral methods (which use fourier basis functions). You can check in wiki http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_method there are some literature, I would suggest you to start with "Chebyshev and Fourier Spectral Methods" by John P. Boyd. - it is very nice for the beginning.

Small note regarding your problem. You can look for solution of your problem in the form:
$$f(x)=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} (a_isin(ix)+b_icos(ix))$$
both $sin(ix)$ and $cos(ix)$ are eigenfunctions of the operator of your problem and they are periodic on the interval $[0;2\pi]$.